# Returning the least number of multiplications it took to find an adjacent pair of duplicate numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I'm not very good with algorithms and I am completely stuck on this and have not been able to find the help I was looking for. The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

Have the function ArrayChallenge(num) take the num parameter being passed and perform the following steps. First take all the single digits of the input number (which will always be a positive integer greater than 1) and add each of them into a list. Then take the input number and multiply it by any one of its own integers, then take this new number and append each of the digits onto the original list. Continue this process until an adjacent pair of the same number appears in the list. Your program should return the least number of multiplications it took to find an adjacent pair of duplicate numbers.

Example: if num is 134 then first append each of the integers into a list: [1, 3, 4]. Now if we take 134 and multiply it by 3 (which is one of its own integers), we get 402. Now if we append each of these new integers to the list, we get: [1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2]. We found an adjacent pair of duplicate numbers, namely 4 and 4. So for this input your program should return 1 because it only took 1 multiplication to find this pair.

Example: if num is 46 then we append these integers onto a list: [4, 6]. If we multiply 46 by 6, we get 276, and appending these integers onto the list we now have: [4, 6, 2, 7, 6]. Then if we take this new number, 276, and multiply it by 2 we get 552. Appending these integers onto the list we get: [4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 5, 5, 2]. Your program should therefore return 2 because it took 2 multiplications to find a pair of adjacent duplicate numbers (5 and 5 in this case).

Comment: What is the rule to pick the multiplier? Why `6` in the first round, why `2` in the second? What would have been the multiplier if there had to be a third round?

Comment: Added more of the instructions @engineersmnky.

Comment: @spickerman I dont think it's giving any particular order in which you do it. The example seems to just be showing the shortest path to the answer multiplying a number by its own digits.

Comment: found same question on Coderbytes , exactly same,  took a while to understand, I am still looking for a Javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be formulated as "Find the shortest path in a decision tree". Where each decision is "Which digit should I use for the next multiplication".

As this decision tree can have infinitely long paths (e.g. start with 12 and always multiply by 1), we can't use a simple depth-first search and instead should implement a breadth first approach.

That means, we should first check for each digit if we reach a desired result, and if not note down the multiplication result. Then, if we didn't find a pair, continue for each noted down number with its digits and so on.

I implemented this as an example in kotlin, but you should be able to transfer this easily to any language:

```kotlin
fun Int.getDigits() = toString().map { it.toString().toInt() }

fun List<Int>.getNum() = joinToString("").toInt()

fun List<Int>.hasAdjacentPair() = zipWithNext().any { (a, b) -> a == b }

fun arrayChallenge(num: Int): Int {
    if (num.getDigits().hasAdjacentPair()) return 0
    val check = mutableListOf(Pair(num.getDigits(), 1))
    while (true) {
        val (digits, multiplications) = check.removeFirst()
        for (digit in digits.distinct()) {
            val multDigits = (digit * digits.getNum()).getDigits()
            if (digits.last() == multDigits.first() || multDigits.hasAdjacentPair()) {
                return multiplications
            }
            check.add(Pair(multDigits, multiplications + 1))
        }
    }
}
```